# Passing a json file to Revit AddIn through Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

passing a json file to a Revit AddIn gives System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the following note on [DA4R Input and Output Files](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/04/da4r-io-logging-updater-and-custom-properties.html#5) and the further discussions that it points to?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, very helpful. 

In case anyone else is having a similar problem, the error went away when I changed my FORGE_WEBHEOOK_URL value from https to http

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation. Glad to hear the issue is resolved, and thank you for sharing the crucial point. Please upvote the answer if you found it useful. Thank you.